# Array con iterator java

Tags: java, pilas, iteradores

Alguien me puede ayudar necesito borrar el primer elemento en un array con iterator el codigo q borra el de el último:

```
public Item borrar(){
  Item it= array[--n]
  array[n]= null;
  if(n>0&&n==array.length/4){
     resize(array.length/2);
}
return it;
}
```

```
public class Prueba<Item> implements Iterable<Item>{
 private Item[] array= (Item []) new Object[i];
 private int n=0;
 public boolean isEmpty(){
return n==0;}
```

Gracias

Comment: por favor colocar todo el código, dado que esta usando la variable `array[]` y no vemos de que trata, adicional a esto la declaración del método esta errada, de acuerdo a lo que entiendo desea retornar un dato de tipo `Item`por lo que el método deberia ser `public Item borrar(){...}`

Comment: En la parte inferior de tu pregunta existe el enlace de eliminar, de otro modo editar como lo hiciste solo te traerá negativos

Comment: Ahora sí ya tienes la respuesta por qué no publicarla y así beneficiar a todos de tu conocimiento?

Comment: Ya lo intente pero solo viene compartir editar reportar

Comment: LA respuesta va abajo en el campo respuesta. Por otra parte si quieres eliminar tu pregunta hay un boton eliminar.